# How to create notification with statusbar text(no icon)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am creating **one notification application**.

But application require `text` instead of `icon/image`.

Reference image:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23hu5xd&s=6

I am using this way to create notification all of the work fine but require text on status bar.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("hiii") // title for notification
                    .setContentText("Hello word") // message for notification
                    .setAutoCancel(false); // clear notification after click

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

**Problem:**
how to set text instead of image. `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)`

Answer (score 2):

You have no choice but to set an image. You are welcome to have the image contain text.

In the screenshot you cited, the app probably has ~100 images to choose from for different percentage levels. You can organize those into a single `LevelListDrawable`, then use the two-parameter version of `setSmallIcon()` to indicate which level you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but i have always different text so how can i manage?

Comment: @Harshid: That is not possible. `setSmallIcon()` requires a resource, and you cannot create a resource at runtime.